# Auditpol Gives Error When Using Category Names In English With Non-English Environment

Tags: c#, .net-4.7.2

I am trying to enable "Object Access->File System" and "Object Access->Registry" programmatically.

When I run `auditpol /get /category:*` command on command prompt, I can see that they are disabled:

[Audit Policies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jit59.png)

I tried to use Powershell script and a function which written in .Net Framework 4.7.2 C#. Both are working fine on computers using Windows in English. Here is the function:

```
static void CallForAuditpol()
{
    string command = $"/set /subcategory:\"File System\" /failure:enable /success:enable";

    Process process = new Process();
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "Auditpol",
        Arguments = command,
        Verb = "runas",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true
    };

    process.StartInfo = startInfo;

    try
    {
        process.Start();
        string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        process.WaitForExit();

        Console.WriteLine("Output:");
        Console.WriteLine(output);
        Console.WriteLine("Command ran successfully");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

But when I call this function on non-English environment, it expects me to write `File System` in native language. I have tried to run this code in Russian and when I wrote `File System` in Russian, it works as expected. Otherwise, it gives error as if parameters are wrong:

[Parameter error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPUbU.png)

Is there any way to make this function independent from system language?